# JSP spring boot and netbeans does give an error and do not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netbeans-8

I am new to spring boot am using Apache netbeans. I did follow all the steps but the application give me the error
"There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500) " and jsp doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    here is my application.properties
    
    server.port=8082
    
    
    
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musadb
    spring.datasource.username=admin
    spring.datasource.password=admin
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    
    
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
    
    logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
    
    my controller code 
    
    /*
     * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
     * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
     */
    package com.springboot.firstwebapplication.spring;
    
    import static com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.CoercionInputShape.String;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author bbc
     */
    @Controller
    public class LoginController {
        
        @RequestMapping("/login")
        public String loginMessage(){
     
            return "login";
        }
       
    }
    
    my main class 
    
    package com.springboot.firstwebapplication.spring;
    
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootFirstWebApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootFirstWebApplication.class, args);
                    
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I am working ");
                    System.out.println("WE are the winners");
                    
        }
    
    }
    
    my login.jsp
    
    
    <html >
    <head>
    <title>First web application</title>
            </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Welcome ${name}!</h1>
    </body>
    
    </html>


my pom.xml file 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    

        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
          
    </parent>   

    <groupId>com.springboot.firstwebapplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-first-web-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-first-web-application</name>
    <description>Spring Boot First Web Application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
        
  <!--   Musa put these -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
         
   
         
            <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    

 
                 <!--   Musa put these ENDED -->

         
         
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: That's too generic error message... you need to investigate some details about it

Comment: been trying sir